# Looks like you dont have any APM services installed. Lets add some

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-cloud, elastic-apm

I am using elastic cloud. My Apm server is running on elastic cloud. But still in Kibana i can see the message "Looks like you don't have any APM services installed. Let's add some!".

My Elastic, Kibana and APM version is 7.8.1

I am trying to use APM in Kibana, and then i will add APM Agents into my Asp.net MVC application.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear in the question whether a .NET APM agent integration has been configured yet in an application that you wish to trace.

Assuming ASP.NET MVC is [ASP.NET Full Framework integration](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/dotnet/current/setup-asp-dot-net.html)

1. Reference [`Elastic.Apm.AspNetFullFramework`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Elastic.Apm.AspNetFullFramework/) nuget package in the application
2. Add `ElasticApmModule` to modules in web.config

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules>
            <add name="ElasticApmModule" type="Elastic.Apm.AspNetFullFramework.ElasticApmModule, Elastic.Apm.AspNetFullFramework" preCondition="managedHandler" />
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

3. [Configure agent settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/dotnet/current/config-all-options-summary.html) in web.config app settings

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- ... -->
<configuration>
    <!-- ... -->
    <appSettings>
        <!-- ... -->
        <add key="ElasticApm:ServerUrl" value="<APM server in Elastic Cloud URL and port>" />
        <add key="ElasticApm:SecretToken" value="<APM server secret token>" />
        <!-- plus any other configuration -->
    </appSettings>
    <!-- ... -->
</configuration>
```

Once this is done, you should start to see APM data for the application in the APM section of Kibana.

Comment: I was seeing that page because i was not configured .NET APM agent in my project. After configuring .NET APM agent its working thanks